# How can I architect polling an external API that previously gave me long-running async operation ID for "Completed Status"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, asynchronous, aws-lambda

A bit of background,
I am utilizing a third-party API, and this API stores account info for my users. Some users do not want to be stored in this third-party service, and when they indicate they want their account deleted, I send a delete request to this external API and immediately receive an Operation ID in the return statement. This delete request in the API is a long-running asynchronous operation that can either take less than a second to complete or an hour to complete.

I can then take this operation ID and poll the API by calling another endpoint with the Operation ID I was given previously to see its completion status ("pending", "completed", etc.)

How might I go about this architecting this using Amazon Web Services? Ideally, the external API would throw a webhook back to one of my Lambda functions when the operation completes, but unfortunately that is not an option this time.

Answer (score 0):

While there are likely several opinions on this I would start with having a Lambda that takes the operation id and asks the remote API if the delete operation for that id has completed.

When a user requests delete you would programmatically create a [Cloudwatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) that is set to run the Lambda at whatever interval makes sense - say every 10 minutes.

The Cloudwatch Event would be created with a parameter to pass to the Lambda - the operation id.  Every time it calls the Lambda it passes this operation id to the Lambda.  The Lambda calls the remote API to see if the delete operation has succeeded for that operation id.

If the delete operation is not done then the Lambda exits and will be run again later by the Cloudwatch Event.  But if the delete operation is complete then the Lambda does whatever is needed for a successful delete - maybe send an email to the user telling them the delete worked or update a database with the status.  But another important part is to remove the Cloudwatch Event that the Lambda was triggered with so that it doesn't keep polling for the delete operation.

The Lambda isn't trivial as it has multiple things to do when the delete is successful.  Some people might even split the operations for a successful delete into other Lambdas.  That's kind of your call and is somewhat dependent on how much devops you are able to deal with.